# Adding the sub section to correct parent section after sorting - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sample code where user can add a section and under the section they can add a sub section. The section and subsections are `sortable` using `ui-sortable` but the problem is when I sort the items, like I swap the Section 1 to Section 2 then try to add new sub section to Section 2, then new element is added to Section 1 which is wrong, the item should be added under the Section 2.

Here is my the demo but not working properly: [Complete Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/BLBe66PewWEU3SoNP7uX?p=preview)

My question is how can add new sub-section into the correct parent section after I sort the sections. Because after sorting the sections, the adding of sub section doesn't do the correct behavior. The sub section goes to the wrong parent section.

My HTML

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="section" class="list">
   <li ng-repeat="parent in section">
       <span>Section {{parent.id}}</span>
       <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="subSection" class="list">
          <ol ng-repeat="child in subSection" ng-if="child.parentId == parent.id">
               <span>SubSection {{child.id}}</span>
          </ol>
          <button ng-click="addSubSection($index + 1)">Add SubSection</button>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="addSection()">Add Section</button>
```

My JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.sortable'])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.section    = [{id: 1}, {id:2}];
   $scope.subSection = [{id:1, parentId: 1}, {id:2, parentId: 1}, {id:3, parentId: 2}];

   $scope.addSection =function(){
      var newId = $scope.section.length +1;

      $scope.section.push({id: newId});
   };

   $scope.addSubSection = function(parentIndex) {
      var newSubId = $scope.subSection.length + 1;
      $scope.subSection.push({id:newSubId, parentId:parentIndex});
   };
}]);
```

Hope I explained it clearly. Thank you

Comment: You seems to be deleting and re-posting questions. Which is likely to lead to question bans. If you need attention, I suggest putting a bounty on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$index` seems unreliable, not sure why (but see below). A working solution for this problem:

1. Change `addSubSection()` to take the parent *object* instead of the index:

   ```
   $scope.addSubSection = function(parent) {
       var newSubId = $scope.subSection.length + 1;
       $scope.subSection.push({id:newSubId, parentId:parent.id});
   };
   ```
2. Pass the parent from the template:

   ```
   <button ng-click="addSubSection(parent)">Add SubSection</button>
   ```

A forked plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/BFR6JLngJiFztR5P6dWa?p=preview

---

The inner sortable is not working when re-arranging subsections. I believe that the way the model is represented, i.e. all subsections are in a flat array and they are arranged to a parent in the view (i.e. the `ng-if`), is leading to bugs. I would probably be better to split the subsections to a separate array per section, e.g. using the scope of the `ng-repeat` or placing the subsections of a section in its model, e.g. `$scope.section = [{id: 1, subSections: [...]}, {id:2, subSections: [...]}];`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help :)